# Is this a suitable structure?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to structure a site to store review documents, in line with the following requirements:

- The following hierarchy is static: A component has documents;
  documents have reviews; reviews have revisions.
- Permissions need to be set at a component and a document level and
  are usually applied to groups but may be applied to individual users. Permissions may be changed.
- Components or documents may need to be removed.
- Adding documents, setting permissions, and removing components/documents all needs to be done programmatically via graph.api.
- There might be a large number of components.

I am thinking of using the following structure:

> mySharePointOnlineSite.com/**[componentId]**/**[documentId]**/**[reviewId]**/**[revisionId]**.docx

Does this look suitable? If not, what problems might I run into, and how should I change it to avoid them?

Comment: See: https://sharepointmaven.com/implement-document-management-system-sharepoint/
Note: SharePoint has a URL length limit of 400 characters, permissions at the component and document level can be complex. SharePoint already has document management features, see link.

Comment: The URL length wouldn't be exceeded because all of the IDs in the string are GUIDs, so there would be a predetermined length that is within the limit. It sounds like the intended use is to use metadata columns, as per your link, instead of a hierarchical structure, so I probably will use that approach. I don't know why permissions on a folder would be complex? I will research the practical differences between the approaches.

Comment: Searching the site indicates that setting permissions by metadata is not supported, so I need to use a folder structure as per my post. e.g. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61623/user-permissions-by-metadata